# inserting into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I am trying my hand at inserting into a mysql db via a php form and im running into an issue where only the second form field is being entered but not the first.

**EDIT**

Here is the code after rewrite.

HTML

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
First Name: <input name="first_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25"><br>
Last Name: <input name="last_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25"><br>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$dbhost  = 'xx';
$dbname  = 'xx';
$dbuser  = 'xx';
$dbpass  = 'xx'; 
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);


$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);


$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customerinfotest VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name');";
echo $query;

mysqli_close($con)
```

The database is connecting fine.. but still the same issue.  First name is giving a null value. Doing a print on the $post gives me:
Array ( [first_name] => [last_name] => collingwood

**EDIT** I changed the form name to firstname without the _ and now it works?

Also, Is this more secure now that it is sqli?  Would the next step in security be to use a prepared statement?

Comment: I would add some debugging code into the page with the SQL statement. Something like: mail('none@example.com', 'My Subject', $sql); This will help you figure out if the SQL is bad, or if you're somehow missing a variable.

Comment: please sanitise user inputs before you get hacked.

Comment: Any sql errors? Try `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to output any errors. Also, please note that your method is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider sanitizing user-defined values or, better yet, use PDO.

Comment: Please use mysqli if you are using the deprecated mysql functions and also it appears that this will be vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Just wait for [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) to register for an account.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I understand I need to sanitize but that is step 2.  This is just a test for me to understand the inserting of data.

Comment: security is step 1, always.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me (added a submit button) but nothing else really, also edited my post.

Comment: Also I am using a hosting company that for whatever reason does not allow PDO on their windows boxes... sigh I learned this after putting in the time to learn and write the sql in pdo format. Guess I will have to use mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first get the posted data into variables, like this (I'm also adding real_escape_string function which is really important):

```
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
```

**Please note the single quotes inside $_POST array**

And then try the query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_customerinfotest (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name')";
```

Lastly, **you shoud use mysqli or PDO functions**, as mysql_* are deprecated.

If it still doesn't work, add `print_r($_POST);` add the beginning of your PHP script, to see if posted data is correct and has correct names.

Comment: Ok, let me give it a whirl.  It looks like I need to figure out how to this in Mysqli from the posts above.  I am using this code as it was the sample code given on w3cschools

Comment: If you're familiar with `mysql_*` functions, use `mysqli_*`. They are almost the same :)

Comment: Try first with your old `mysql_*` functions, to see if syntax is OK and that there are no other mistakes. Then change to mysqli. Please note that most `mysqli_*` functions need the link identifier as first argument. That link is what you get when you connect to the database. See <http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php>

Comment: I did figure that out after googling the error.  I have changed everything over and I am still getting the same issue.. first name is not storing.  See my original comment edit.

Comment: Curious what firstname and lastname are you testing with?

Comment: Wazy, they both come from form fields.  I have edited the code above which should show the html and the $post

Comment: As noted above, I switched the form name from first_name to firstname and then changed the $_POST['first_name'] to $_POST['firstname']  and it now works.  Not sure why the _ was throwing it off.  The _ in the last_name does not seem to have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

In response to OP's edit this works fine for me:

Index.html

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
First Name: <input name="first_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25"><br>
Last Name: <input name="last_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Submit.php

```
<?php 
    $dbhost  = '';
    $dbname  = '';
    $dbuser  = '';
    $dbpass  = ''; 
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);


    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO test.tbl_customerinfotest VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name');";
    echo $query;

    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    echo mysqli_error();

    mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

It is much better that you use mysqli functions now instead of the deprecated mysql_* ones.
Read the docs here https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php for a more detailed explanation of why you should use mysqli_* over mysql_*.

Comment: I added the code and get the following output.  Connected to databaseINSERT INTO tbl_customerinfotest (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('','collingwood')

Comment: You see that there is no firstname in your query. See Marcelo's answer as it is more detailed and redundant for me to repeat most of it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see it should work but I think there is a part of code that you haven't posted that is messing things up.

While coding PHP you should always have PHP warnings enabled!

Like others mentioned you needs to sanitise your data before using it, this means you have to test it for any unwanted input (this is where regular expressions functions are very handy)

Also your HTML code has unclosed tags!

```
<input name="first_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25"><br>
```

should be

```
<input name="first_name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25" /><br />
```

Comment: For some reason the _ in first_name was the cause.  Changing it to just firstname fixed the issue.

Comment: that's why I was wondering about the rest of your code, maybe there was another field named like this one and they both got messed up.

Comment: Anyway, glad you solved it, but try following the given advices and sanitise you data before using it, that also means to check for existence (things that PHP would warn you about if you activate PHP warnings during development)

Comment: This is my first PHP code so I appreciate the advice.  I need to take some more tutorials to understand how to use the php warnings.  And you are right.. just going back to the code there was another field with that name that I had thought was commented out but wasn't... so there you go.  Thanks man!